# operations on real functions

Tags: functions

If $f$ and $g$ are two real functions such that domain of $f$ is $D_1$ and domain of $g$ is $D_2$ both being subsets of $\mathbb R$ . My book says that the function $f+g$ will have the domain ($D_1 \cap D_2$). Why is this? And if $f$ and $g$ have co-domain $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively such that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are subsets of set of real numbers then what will be the co-domain of $f+g$?

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $f+g$ is $D_1\cap D_2$ because $(f+g)(x)$ is defined as $f(x)+g(x)$, and you can only calculate that value if $f(x)$ is defined (i.e., $x\in D_1$) and $g(x)$ is defined (i.e., $x\in D_2$).

So, $x$ is in the domain of $f+g$ only if $x\in D_1$ **and** $x\in D_2$, or in other words, if $x\in D_1\cap D_2$.

---

You cannot say anything about the co-domain of $f+g$, however.

For example, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$, then the co-domain of $f+g$ is $\{0\}$. On the other hand, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$, then the co-domain of $f+g$ is the same as the co-domain of $f$.

Comment: Can we say anything about the range of f+g if the range of f is R1 and the range of g is R2 ?

Comment: @VarunChandra Like I already explained, the answer to that question is **no**. For example, you can create two functions, both of which have a range of $\mathbb R$, and their sum can have the range of $\{0\}$.